# Failed to switch database using CnosDB client

Tags: database, client, cnosdb

There are multiple databases in my database system, and the names of some databases are in mixed case. When I use the client to switch databases, it fails.

To Reproduce(use cnosdb-cli)

1. create database 'OceanicStation';
2. show databases;
3. \c OceanicStaion; or \c 'OceanicStaion'; or use 'OceanicStation';

[image]

I expect to switch correctly